# react-router v6: passing in function as parameter to navigate refreshes the whole page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a drop down list menu

Here I am pushing an "Edit" menu item, where when it's clicked, the **action** function will be called, and it will navigate to another route's component, passing in **state** which will be received on the target component

[image]

```
   listActionMenus.push({
      label: "Edit",
      action: () => {
        navigate('/somePath', {
          state: {
            developerIds: [45, 46, 47]
          },
        });
      },
    });
```

This works. I am able to receive the state's data on the target navigated to component. But the super weird thing is, if i add a function to the state like this

```
listActionMenus.push({
  label: "Edit",
  action: () => {
    navigate('/somePath', {
      state: {
        developerIds: [45, 46, 47],
        onSaveSuccess: () => { // function
          alert("ha");
        },
      },
    });
  },
});
```

then the whole application craps out and refreshes the whole page. I complete lost as to what's triggered this. I am not even calling the onSaveSuccess on the target component yet, just simply passing in the function freaks the whole page out.

Can someone help me? Been stuck for days. If you think this is not enough information I will gladly add more details.

Comment: I don't think it's allowed to pass a function as state to the browser history. Here it says, that "object can be anything that can be serialized": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState (and React Router uses the Browser History internally)

Comment: @NilsHartmann makes sense, i guess context and redux are my only options then, which i was trying to avoid. Thanks!